# parameterized-trigger is not triggering the downstream job if I uncheck Build without parameters why

Tags: jenkins

Last few lines of the upstream job

> D:\HudsonSlave\workspace\prksh_coes_win\Dev>echo "testing" 
>   "testing"
>
> D:\HudsonSlave\workspace\prksh_coes_win\Dev>exit 0 
>   [parameterized-trigger] Downstream builds will not be triggered.
>   Finished: SUCCESS

this happens only when I uncheck

> Trigger build without parameters

on the upstream job

Answer (score 3):

My Bad, I forgot to include "Current Build Parameters". Which is available under add build parameters.